# Debugging android that runs on virtual box

Tags: android

I really wanted a fast android emulatoe, and decided to install a vm with android.
How can i debug the machine from my ide?

Comment: You mean you're running something like Oracle Vitrtual Box in order to emulate Ubuntu under Windows?

Comment: in order to emulate android under windows

Comment: Fow which reason Windows-based android emulator is not good though?